# How to extract dynamic string from a text using regular expression

Tags: regex, vba, parsing

I am working on the below sample text

> 7. text here text here —(1) Without prejudice to any special rights previously conferred on  the  holders  of  any existing  shares  or class of shares but subject to the Act, shares in the company may be issued by the directors. (2) Shares referred to in paragraph (1) may be issued with preferred, deferred, or other special rights or restrictions, whether in regard to dividend, voting, return of capital, or otherwise, as the directors, subject to any ordinary resolution of the company, determine.

I want to split the text in the following manner

> 7. text here text here —

> (1) Without prejudice to any special rights previously conferred on  the  holders  of  any existing  shares  or class of shares but subject to the Act, shares in the company may be issued by the directors.

> (2) Shares referred to in paragraph (1) may be issued with preferred, deferred, or other special rights or restrictions, whether in regard to dividend, voting, return of capital, or otherwise, as the directors, subject to any ordinary resolution of the company, determine.

The text is dynamic in nature and instead of `(1)`, `(2)` we could get `(a)`, `(b)`, `a.`, `b.`, `i`, `ii`, `iii`. To handle the first problem statement, I have used the below regular expression in VBA:

```
Pattern = "([(][\d][)])([A-Z,a-z,.,\-,’,(,),_, ,:,\n,“,”,"",:,;,—,-,\—,\t,\r,]*)"
```

I am looking for a solution to split the contents but not looking for a solution specific in VBA or regular expressions. Any other approach is also appreciated.

Comment: In order to split a string, you must clearly settle the splitting rules. Would you like to split the first string in order to extract each proposition. I mean each part ending in dot, except the first  one? Then split it by "--"? Are there any other rules to be applied? When you say "not looking for a solution specific in VBA or regular expressions", what do you have in mind, since you tagged the question as `VBA` and `regex`? Then, where from to be extracted this pieces of text? Are they paragraphs in Word, or what?

Answer (score 0):

You did not answer the clarification questions, but please, try the next VBA function:

```
Function SpecSplitText(x As String) As String
  Dim strFin As String, strInt As String, arr, arr1, El
  
  arr = Split(x, "—"):
  strFin = arr(0) & vbCrLf
  arr1 = Split(arr(1), ".")
  
  For Each El In arr1
    If Len(LTrim(El)) = 1 Then
        strInt = LTrim(El) & ". "
    Else
        strFin = strFin & strInt & LTrim(El) & "." & vbCrLf
        strInt = ""
    End If
  Next
  strFin = left(strFin, Len(strFin) - 3)
  SpecSplitText = strFin
End Function
```

You can test the function using the next simple test `Sub`:

```
Sub testSpecSplitText()
    Dim x As String, y As String, z As String
    x = "7. text here text here —(1) Without prejudice to any special rights previously conferred on the holders of any existing shares or class of shares but subject to the Act, shares in the company may be issued by the directors. (2) Shares referred to in paragraph (1) may be issued with preferred, deferred, or other special rights or restrictions, whether in regard to dividend, voting, return of capital, or otherwise, as the directors, subject to any ordinary resolution of the company, determine."
    y = "8. text here text here —a. Without prejudice to any special rights previously conferred on the holders of any existing shares or class of shares but subject to the Act, shares in the company may be issued by the directors. b. Shares referred to in paragraph (1) may be issued with preferred, deferred, or other special rights or restrictions, whether in regard to dividend, voting, return of capital, or otherwise, as the directors, subject to any ordinary resolution of the company, determine."
    z = "9. text here text here —I Without prejudice to any special rights previously conferred on the holders of any existing shares or class of shares but subject to the Act, shares in the company may be issued by the directors. II Shares referred to in paragraph (1) may be issued with preferred, deferred, or other special rights or restrictions, whether in regard to dividend, voting, return of capital, or otherwise, as the directors, subject to any ordinary resolution of the company, determine."
    
    Debug.Print SpecSplitText(x)
    Debug.Print SpecSplitText(y)
    Debug.Print SpecSplitText(z)
End Sub
```

But, if the text in discussion uses "etc." or an abbreviation ending in dot (.), you must enumerate them to escape.

Comment: @Lal Ansari: Didn't you find same time to test the above code?